# "Учёного учить - только портить" - сказуемое и подлежашее

Tags: синтаксис

Учёного учить - только портить. Что сказуемое и подлежашее и чем выражено подлежашее

Comment: «Чем выражено подлежашее». Они все у вас шепелявят.

Comment: Смахивает на домашнее задание, а мы почему-то отвечаем.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Задавайте вопросы, пожалуйста, понятнее и оформляйте их соответствующим образом. В данном случае оба главных члена выражены инфинитивом: ***учить*** (подлежащее) и ***портить*** (сказуемое).

Answer (score 0):

Учить - подлежащее,портить - сказуемое